# PLSQL trigger compilation error

Tags: plsql, triggers, oracle10g, plsqldeveloper

PLSQL trigger created with compilation error and I cannot update the table.

```
create or replace trigger dis_salary_changes
before update of Salary on system.emp
for each row
when (new.Eno in('E1','E2','E3','E4','E5'))
declare
    sal_diff integer;
    begin
        sal_diff := :new.salary - :old.salary;
        dbms_output.put_line('Old Salary= '|| :old.Salary);
        dbms_output.put_line('New Salary= '|| :new.Salary);
        dbms_output.put_line('Salary difference= '|| :sal_diff);
    end;
/
```

Comment: Use `show errors`or query the `user_errors` view to see the actual errors for the object.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trigger is more or less OK, apart from a few things.

First of all, don't use `SYSTEM` schema for your *business*. Create another user and test your skills there (or, use one of pre-installed ones, such as `SCOTT` or `HR`, if they are there). You might screw the database up if you continue working in `SYSTEM`.

As of your code, the only syntax error is in the last `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` call - remove the colon in front of the `SAL_DIFF` variable:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER dis_salary_changes
   BEFORE UPDATE OF Salary
   ON SYSTEM.emp
   FOR EACH ROW
   WHEN (new.Eno IN ('E1',
                     'E2',
                     'E3',
                     'E4',
                     'E5'))
DECLARE
   sal_diff   INTEGER;
BEGIN
   sal_diff := :new.salary - :old.salary;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Old Salary= ' || :old.Salary);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('New Salary= ' || :new.Salary);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Salary difference= ' || :sal_diff);
                                                  ^
                                                  remove it
END;
/
```

Also, once you calculate the difference, you don't do anything with that information. Is it intentional?

Answer (score -1):

```
create or replace trigger dis_SAL_changes
before update of SAL on emp
for each row
when (new.EMPNO in('E1','E2','E3','E4','E5'))
declare
    SAL integer;
    begin
        SAL := :new.SAL - :old.SAL;
        dbms_output.put_line('Old SAL= '|| :old.SAL);
        dbms_output.put_line('New SAL= '|| :new.SAL);
        dbms_output.put_line('SAL difference= '|| :SAL);
    end;
```

TRIGGER DIS_SAL_CHANGES compiled